# git doesn't push .env file on the server

Tags: git, laravel, heroku

on my local server in my laravel app I have .env file.

to push changes to the server I use

`git add .
git commit -m "something"
git push heroku master`

but when I use `heroku git:clone -a myapp` in the cloned app there is no **.env** file... there is only **.env.development** file.

Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check your `.gitignore` file if you have one there. If your git repo was set up for you automatically or imported from another project then it is likely that it is being ignored by default.

If it is in there then simply remove it to include your `.env` file in your next commit.

Comment: that's it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why anywhere anybody does not push `.env`? they just push `.env.example`.

Comment: @AmerllicA this is because the `.env` file usually contains sensitive or localised information. In the case of sensitive information, like API keys, authentication keys etc, you don’t want these sitting in version control where they are publically accessible. It may not be a huge deal if the repository is private, but if it was public on something like GitHub then anyone could find and use that information. For localised information, this is different per environment and needs to be setup anyway, so it’s less error prone to just copy or move `.env.example` to `.env` than it is to manually edit

Comment: How do I ignore .env from git while heroku will not ignore it?

Answer (score 4):

Laravel, by default, ignores the `.env` - this is very much intended, as your different environments should technically have, well, different `env` files. It also helps you from not submitting credentials (such as for your database) into version control.

I would recommend you continue to follow this intended practice and look into using heroku config variables:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 1):

Open file text `.gitignore` on root folder, git will skip file and folder in `.gitignore`. You just delete all text. Then review git status.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces surrounding "=" in your environment file `.env`. Now try to push it.

Run `heroku config:push --overwrite` because it won't overwrite existing variables by default.

If the problem still persists, try this [heroku-config](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config) : It provides a way for you to push/pull your Heroku environment to use locally.